# How to replace only a specific word from the end of the string in PHP?

Tags: php, string, replace, str-replace

I have two string variables like this

```
$string1 = 'this is my house';
$string2 = 'this house is mine';
```

I need a method to replace 'house' with 'dog' only if 'house' is the last word of the string.

For example, this code

```
function replace($input_string, $search_string, $replace_string){
   //do the magic here!
}
$string1 = replace($string1, 'house','dog');
$string2 = replace($string2, 'house','dog');

echo $string1;
echo $string2;
```

desired return will be...

```
this is my dog
this house is mine
```

Comment: I don't get it... it won't return "this house is mine" after that operation, you mean it's a desired result? "it will returns..."

Comment: What is `replace`? What do you mean by `last word of the string`, last occurrence in string, or word? Showing some attempt and other examples would help. e.g. `this is my house....` should have `house` replaced?

Comment: yeah you mean `str_replace`? really hard to understand your question... you want to replace only last word of the sentence if it's a house to dog?

Comment: You've tagged this question with PHP 5.3. You know that 5.3 hasn't been supported for over 6 years (with no security updates or anything)? If you're actually running 5.3, you are exposed and should upgrade as soon as possible.

Comment: `do the magic here` adds nothing to the question `preg_replace` and `$` may be a starting place for you. Question is to vague currently though. https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the conditions you mentioned you can do something like below. Find the word count and then check is home available in the string and then find the index of the house . So then you can check does that index match to last index of the word array `(count($wordArray)) - 1)`

```
$string1 = 'this is my house';
    $string2 = 'this house is mine';
    $wordArray = explode(' ', $string1); // make the array with words
    //check the conditions you want 
    if (in_array('house', $wordArray) && (array_search('house', $wordArray) == (count($wordArray)) - 1)) {
        $string1 = str_replace('house', 'dog', $string1);
    }
    echo $string1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for something like this:

```
function replace($str,$from,$to){
    $str = preg_replace('~('.preg_quote($from).')$~',$to,$str);
    return $str;
}
```

Please note that documentation says to not to use `preg_quote` in `preg_replace`, but honestly I don't know why. If you know, please comment.

Comment: Imho, questions without any actual attempt to solve their issue shouldn't be answered. That just reduces this site to a free coding service.

Comment: yeah, but sometimes you just have no idea where to start (maybe that's not the case)

Comment: The note about `preg_quote` is for the replace, not the pattern.

Comment: after my answer wasn't even picked as a right answer, even when it was first, I do agree with the first comment and will keep that as an absolute rule